# How to implement WebClient.UploadFileAsync with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, http

I have the following function

```
public bool UploadFirmware(string ipAddress)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri($"https://{ipAddress}/upload.html");
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string selectedFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                if (selectedFileName == string.Empty)
                    return false;
                else
                {
                    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                    {
                        webClient.UploadFileAsync(url, "POST", selectedFileName);
                        webClient.UploadFileCompleted += WebClient_UploadFileCompleted; 
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

This function works correctly and it is able to upload the file to the destination. However, I wanted to change the WebClient with and HttpClient as I want to upload files to multiple destinations at the same time without making a new WebClient for each request.
My HttpClient is as follows:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadFirmware(string[] ipAddresses)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string selectedFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                if (selectedFileName == string.Empty)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                else
                {
                    var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    var array = File.ReadAllBytes(selectedFileName);
                    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(array);
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
                    multiForm.Add(fileContent, "files", Path.GetFileName(selectedFileName));
                    var url = $"https://{ipAddresses[0]}/upload.html";
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, multiForm);
                    var test = response.Content;
                   
                    return true;
                   
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

With my current implementation the response is 400, Bad request, leading me to think that I have not created the request correctly as of yet. My request is if you could point me to the right direction, what am I doing wrong? Is HttpClient needed? It might be that creating multiple WebClient would not pose a problem.

**PS:** The files that I am sending are of type .fw and currently I am trying to get one response to get through. After I am able to do a single request correctly I will be using Tasks.